# Wistia Video Custom Action

Tags: javascript, api, video, wistia

If I have two wistia videos embedded on a page, is there a way for me to stop/pause the current one playing when I click play on the other one?

The idea is I have a video playing (wistia embed) as a background with no sound or controls. When my custom "play" button is clicked, it pops up that same video in a separate popup embed I got from wistia. The issue is I want the background video to stop playing when the pop-up one is clicked.

This is my background video ...

```
<div class="wistia_responsive_padding" style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;">
  <div class="wistia_responsive_wrapper" style="height:100%;left:0;position:absolute;top:0;width:100%;">
    <div class="wistia_embed wistia_async_inij4whj9t videoFoam=true" style="height:100%;width:100%">&nbsp;
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is my pop video..

```
<script src="https://fast.wistia.com/embed/medias/hez3u29kov.jsonp" async></script>
<script src="https://fast.wistia.com/assets/external/E-v1.js" async></script>
<span class="wistia_embed wistia_async_hez3u29kov popover=true popoverContent=link" style="display:inline">
  <a href="#" class="play-hero-video">
    <img src="//air-watch.com/uploads/global-media/home-hero-pplay-icon-2x.png" onmouseover="this.src='//air-watch.com/uploads/global-media/Home_Hero_Hover_Play_icon@2x.png';" onmouseout="this.src='//air-watch.com/uploads/global-media/home-hero-pplay-icon-2x.png';" alt=""> 
    <span>Play video</span>
  </a>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's [an example of how to do that](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/wistia-pause-other-videos-on-play) on Glitch.

Comment: this worked great thank you... one thing.. when i close the pop up video.. i wanted the background one to start playing again :/ is that possible?

Comment: also i will go ahead and accept your answer as it did solve my initial issue

Comment: Yes, totally possible! You could bind to the "popoverhide" event for the video in the popover (see https://wistia.com/doc/popover-customization#popoverhide), and when that happens, call .play() on the background video.